# foundation 5 responsive design layout

Tags: zurb-foundation

I cant wrap my head around properly creating a responsive design using **foundation 5** when dealing with grid systems.

Is it imperative that everything be set the column width using the grid system?
To be more clear, does every element on the page require a number of columns for each width (small, medium, large) for the site to be considered truly responsive? Or is it sufficient to set width in % and ems and simple explicit media queries to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Foundation 5, but in principle, no, you do not even need a grid system at all to be responsive. As you rightly suspected, media queries used to rearrange the elements you want to move for different size screens will make any page responsive. And yes, set things in em units or %ages - especially the media query breakpoints.

Grids are of use if your page content naturally needs to be displayed in a grid like fashion.

By the way, you would probably have had an answer much earlier if you had tagged it correctly. Responsive design makes it a CSS question, so it needs a CSS tag! I just happened to see this because I was searching for something else.

Comment: i think i got my answer, but just to clarify:
i sometimes buy html/css themes built with frameworks like **foundation** or **bootstrap** and notice that almost every element or block is using the **grid system** to achieve most of the responsive requirements. and i just thought that this is sometimes illogical and causes unnecessary code bloat and isnt that semantic to begin with.  
                   PS: i think i did try to add the css tag first, but being a first timer i was told i needed reputation to use this tag. or it could be another tag that made me forget about re-adding the css tag

Comment: I agree with you about the code bloat of frameworks, and they do other bad things as well... like Bootstrap which fixes the font size so that people with poor vision can't do text-zoom only in IE - bad for Accessibility. Also you can recognise a bootstrap site the moment you land on their front page - they all look so samey! But there are several simple grid systems around where you can just follow the principles explained and copy the code for the grid size you want. Just Google for "css responsive grids".